# Is expectation finite?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider an integer valued non-negative random variable $X$ Assume that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\left(P(X\geq n)\right)}{n}=c$$

where $0>c>-\infty.$ Is it possible to argue that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is finite?

Comment: The identity $\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{n \ge 1} \Pr[X \ge n]$ may be useful.

Comment: @Misha Oh! yes, this formula with Cauchys root test does the trick , Thanks!